# How to mirror exactly the left admin menu on front end?

Tags: functions

Want to mirror the left admin menu on front end, exactly as it appears on backend...

I'd like to do this for a multisite so it seems like a seamless transition. I can add more menu items and hide others through some simple functions, but have had a hard time getting the front end to act like the back.

For one, I cant get the sub menus to hover... trying to get rid of hover intent and so forth... but that's getting too deep. Really just trying to produce the left admin menu on front end.

Comment: Is the admin bar disabled on the front end? It should display by default unless a user specifies that they do not want it to show.

Comment: @CourtneyIvey, I'm referring to the left hand bar, not the top one.